# Automated volume mounts on mac

Tags: applescript

Being a new script developer I need to automatically mount an **afp**    volume when a server starts up. I have written a simple script - it compiles correctly and when I click the "**run**" button it works perfectly. Then saved it as an application but when I double click it or put it in the start up items it keeps waiting for the connect to be clicked. The volume to be mounted has a user but NO password.

Any help much appreciated.

```
delay 5
with timeout of 2 seconds
    try
        mount volume "afp://server/volume" as user name "user" with password ""
    on error
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end try
end timeout
```

Comment: I can remember that there were always issues with mounting afp-volumes with empty passwords via applescript.

Comment: If you want to mount a volume at start you can add it to the start items or add it the Finder sidebar, then it mounts if you click on it.